# JMockit hang on in unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

I use `JUnit` for unit-testing. I use `JMockit` to mock up some `java.util` classes in my unit tests:

```
   new MockUp<PrintWriter>() { //HERE UNIT TESTS HANG ON
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Mock(invocations = 5)
        public void print(String s) {
            System.out.print(s);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Mock(invocations = 1)
        public void flush() {}
    };
```

**Problem:** My unit test just hang on at mockup definition.

**Question:** May you suppose the problem?

**My dependencies:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.jmockit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Same here with Mac Os x. It stucks in `MacosxVirtualMachine.read(int, byte[], int, int) line: not available [native method]`

Comment: @perencia so JMockit can't mock methods which has calls to native functions. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure that is a problem..

Comment: You should invert the order between the `junit` and `jmockit` dependencies, so that JMockit can properly install its integration with JUnit. There is no need for the `-javaagent` parameter, provided you are using a JDK 1.6+ with a working "Attach API" implementation (I recommend using the Oracle JDKs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, have a look on this page:

http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1123/trunk/www/installation.html

at the step 4.

You are probably missing a jmockit agent as default VM argument:

```
-javaagent:<path_to>\jmockit.jar
```

Comment: thanks. I use jdk 1.7. I'll try your solution a few hours later.

Comment: My pleasure. I also use 1.7, but still had some trouble without the jmockit agent. I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Note: the current version for that page is at http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/gettingStarted.html.

Answer (score 1):

The test class below works fine for me, using JMockit 1.7.

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class PrintWriterTest
{
    @Test
    public void useMockedPrintWriter() throws Exception {
        new MockUp<PrintWriter>() {
            @Mock(invocations = 5) void print(String s) { System.out.print(s); }
            @Mock(invocations = 1) void flush() {}
        };

        writeTextFileWithFiveLines();
    }

    void writeTextFileWithFiveLines() throws Exception {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("temp.txt");
        pw.print("line1");
        pw.print("line2");
        pw.print("line3");
        pw.print("line4");
        pw.print("line5");
        pw.flush();
    }

    @Test
    public void useNonMockedPrintWriter() throws Exception {
        writeTextFileWithFiveLines();
    }
}
```

Note 1: The use of `@RunWith(JMockit.class)` above is not required; its advantage is only that it avoids the need to either have jmockit.jar precede junit.jar in the classpath *or* to have `-javaagent:jmockit.jar` as a JVM initialization parameter.

Note 2: The `invocations = n` constrains used above are entirely optional.